# How to remove ".aspx" from url in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web-config, global-asax

I want to remove ".aspx" from my web appliaction url. also I have using webservices.

If I use below code web services is not working.

Global.asax

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      String WebsiteURL = Request.Url.ToString();
      String[] SplitedURL = WebsiteURL.Split('/');
      String[] Temp = SplitedURL[SplitedURL.Length - 1].Split('.');

      // This is for aspx page
      if (!WebsiteURL.Contains(".aspx") && Temp.Length == 1)
      {
          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Temp[0].Trim()))

              Context.RewritePath(Temp[0] + ".aspx");
      }
}
```

for Eg:-

Actual page is DEFAULT.aspx, but I want to show DEFAULT in address bar. So I used Global.asax to remove (.aspx). It's working fine. but Web service is not working(Default.asmx)

Comment: I'd consider using the [`URLRewrite`](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module) module for IIS.  Not necessarily the easiest to use, but very powerful and will do what I believe you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a module that will handle this for you without having to directly manipulate the urls, as described here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx.

---

Install the package, `Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls`.

In your `RouteConfig`, the extensionless urls are enabled using:

```
routes.EnableFriendlyUrls();
```

You can generate friendly urls using extension methods, for example, to generate /Foo/bar/34, you can use:

```
<a href="<%: FriendlyUrl.Href("~/Foo", "bar", 34) %>">Click me</a>
```